# Pre-compiling Angular.js template before loading with Node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, templates

Im learning Angular and trying to build it into my existing Node.js framework.

Before Angular, I used Handlebars.js as my templating engine & would build the context using Node then compile it with the HTML template before writing the headers and loading the HTML essentially like this:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
for(var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {

    var source = files[i].toString('utf8');

    // Handlebars
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var html = template(context);   

    res.write(html);

}
res.end();
```

Now, because Angular is on the client-side, I have to first load the DOM template then have Angular get and compile the data which not only produces a noticeable delay, but seems cumbersome from a coding standpoint since I have to use one server-side controller to load the DOM, then another server-side controller that angular uses to grab the needed data.

1) Load HTML template:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
for(var i = 0; i<files.length; ++i) {

    var html = files[i].toString('utf8');
    res.write(html);

}
res.end();
```

2) Load Angular Controller

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('/test').then(function(response){ 

        $scope.context = response.data;

    });     
}
```

3) Angular controller calls Server-side controller to grab & return the scope

```
if(req.method==='GET'){

    var context = {test : 'this is the test context'};

    res.json(context);  
}
```

Is there any way to pre-compile the template with the context using Angular BEFORE the template is loaded? How is this kind of thing normally done?

Answer (score 0):

No. That's the task that was solved with Angular Universal in Angular 2. In Angular 1, the app can be prerendered for SEO purposes to static HTML, but it won't preserve dynamic behaviour.

You can speed up the app by adding payload to initial response and designing the services accordingly.

Basically, payload module should be dynamically inserted by server side controller:

```
<script>
(function () {

var httpPayload = {
  '/test': [200, /*JSON response string*/, /*optional subrequest headers*/],
  ...
};

var templatePayload = {
  '/template.html': /*template HTML string*/,
  ...
};

angular.module('app.payload', [])
.run(function($http, $cacheFactory, $templateCache) {
  var httpPayloadCache = $http.defaults.cache = $cacheFactory('httpPayload');
  Object.keys(httpPayload).forEach(function (key) {
    httpPayloadCache.put(key, httpPayload[key]));
  });

  Object.keys(templatePayload).forEach(function (key) {
    $templateCache.put(key, templatePayload[key]));
  });

});

})();
</script>
```

And the app should load optional payload module in order for it to take effect:

```
try {
  angular.module('app.payload');
} catch (e) {
  angular.module('app.payload', []);
}

angular.module('app', ['app.payload'])...
```

A cleaner approach may presume that all data is contained within model services, and they are designed in the way that they can be hydrated directly with no `$http` involved.

Directive and route templates can be pre-built with Grunt/Gulp plugin to be served statically (all they do is generating `$templateCache.put(...)` statements).